# Can i set git push permissions for local machine?

Tags: git, permissions, branch, push

I know i can set permissions on GIT to deny users push access to the master branch, but I don't have access to set these permissions.

I still want to disable write access to the master branch for my developers machines. Is there something i can configure on their local machines to let them write to only one branch?

Comment: Why can't you set permissions on the remote? Is it hosted by another company, like GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal way would be to install **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)** on the central server, because you can then control those ACL from your workstation (by modifying the special admin repo '`gitolite-admin`')

If this isn't possible, then you have to deploy a hook, like a [pre-push hook](http://gitolite.com/) ([here is an example](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87c86dd14abe8db7d00b0df5661ef8cf147a72a3/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample)) in order to check the remote ref: if it is origin/master, then you can exit with 1 (fail), and that will cancel the push.

But that is a hook that need to be deployed for all the users, which is less convenient than having a centralized access control solution like gitolite.